# Eigen vector in SVD

Tags: matlab

Im going to compute the eigen value and eigen vector from my Matrix data fro the classification.

The rows represent the different classes and the columns represent the features.

So, for example if I have

```
 X= 
  [2 3 4]  
  [3 2 4]   
  [4 5 6]  
  [8 9 0]
```

**I have to use SVD instead of PCA because the matrix is not square.**

What I have done are:

1. Compute the mean for each row. So I have

   ```
   Mean=  
     M1  
     M2  
     M3  
     M4
   ```
2. Substract my matrix **X** with the Mean

   ```
    Substract= 

   [2-M1 3-M1 4-M1]  
   [3-M2 2-M2 4-M2]   
   [4-M3 5-M3 6-M3]  
   [8-M4 9-M4 0-M4]
   ```
3. Covariance Matrix = (Substract*Substract^t)/(4-1)
4. [U,S,V] = svd(X)

Are all my step right? By compute the mean for each row (as the classes)?

If I want to project my data into eigen space (for dimensionality reduction), which is the eigen vector (U or V)??

Answer (score 1):

You can do PCA whether your matrix is square or not. In fact, your matrix is rarely square because it has a form `n*p` where `n` is the number of observations and `p` is the number of features. Thus you can use MATLAB's `pricomp` function

```
[W, pc] = princomp(data);
```

where `W` is a weight matrix and `pc` is the principal component score. You can see your data projected into the principal component space by,

```
plot(pc(1,:),pc(2,:),'.');
```

which shows your data in the first- and second- principal component directions.